# What will happen if bean having prototype scope included in bean having singleton scope

Tags: spring

I have a class having singleton scope (car) and it contain reference of another class(Steering) having prototype scope.Now whenever I am trying to print hashcode of class having singleton scope and class having prototype scope , value of hashcode is coming same.

```
Car car=(Car)ac.getBean("SingletonBean");
Steering steering=car.getSteering();
System.out.println("singleton obj >"+car.hashCode());
System.out.println("singleton obj >"+steering.hashCode());
Car car1=(Car)ac.getBean("SingletonBean");
Steering steering1=car.getSteering();
System.out.println("singleton obj >"+car1.hashCode());
System.out.println("singleton obj >"+steering1.hashCode());
```

The hashcode of car is coming same because same object is being returned as its scope is singleton. That's why hashcode of steering is also coming same because same car object is being returned. But if Steering is in prototype scope , its hashcode should be different ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is perfectly reasonable. Since there is only one bean of type `Car`, there is obviously only one `Steering` object being used and hence the same hash code.

If however you where to have another type, say `Bus` and you had a Spring managed bean of that type that had a dependency on `Steering`, then the steering object injected into the bean of type `Bus` would not be the same as the one injected into the bean of type `Car`.

In the following code snippet, the assertion would pass

```
Car car=(Car)ac.getBean("SingletonBean");
Bus bus = (Bus)ac.getBean("Bus");

assert (bus.getSteering() != car.getSteering());
```

Answer (score 0):

Prototype scope means that you get a different object from the spring context each time you ask it for the bean name in question. But when you inject something into a singleton bean you're only asking the context for the dependencies *once* (at injection time). The singleton bean will get one reference to the prototype bean and then hang onto that same object from then on.

Answer (score 0):

Method Injection will let us change the way prototype-scoped are handled inside singleton-scoped bean.

Follow this [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/method-injection-spring)